# Why does Spring boot + PostgreSQL (11) throw an error with an Entity using id strategy Identity?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot

This is the Code:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
```

If I change the strategy to `GenerationType.Auto`, it works.  But not fine...
the id does not go through consistently,

I work with Springboot and PostgreSQL 11.

Error Code:

> Hibernate: select currval('"address"_"id"_seq') 2019-03-21
> 15:19:18.430  WARN 14880 --- [nio-8080-exec-4]
> o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState:
> 42602 2019-03-21 15:19:18.430 ERROR 14880 --- [nio-8080-exec-4]
> o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: unknown syntax
> Position: 16 2019-03-21 15:19:18.455 ERROR 14880 ---
>
> [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    :
> Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path
> [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could
> not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is
> org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract
> ResultSet] with root cause
>
> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: unknown syntax
> Position: 16

Comment: `currval('"address"_"id"_seq')` should be `currval('address_id_seq')` this looks like a serious bug with Hibernate

Comment: This looks like a mix of Identity and sequence. I think AUTO might default it to sequence (which is what you should use anyways..)